On the average of the sum of the distances from a point to the vertices of a regular polygon
Consider a regular $n$ sided polygon inscribed in a unit circle. let $A1, ... , An$ be the verticies of the regular polygon. Does this limit exist? And if so, what is it equal to?
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_1^nA_1A_n
$$
when $n$ tends to $+ \infty$
I was thinking on using Viviani's theorem by placing the point on $A_1$, but I have not managed to prove it for a regular $n$ sided polygon...

I will presume that you are asking about the average distance from a fixed vertex ($A_1$) to the other $(n-1)$ vertices of the polygon, which is given by
$$\dfrac1n \sum_{k = 1}^n A_1A_k$$
First notice that the vertices of the regular $n$-gon in question can be described by the $n$th roots of unity. The sum in question hence reduces to
$$\dfrac1n \sum_{k = 1}^n \left\lvert\exp \left(\dfrac{2\pi i k}n\right) - 1\right\rvert$$ This is precisely the Riemann sum of $\lvert e^{2\pi i x} - 1\rvert$ (with $0 \leq x \leq 1$). As $n \to \infty$, the sum becomes
$$\int_0^1 \lvert e^{2\pi i x} - 1\rvert \, \mathrm{d}x$$
Now observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\lvert e^{2\pi i x} - 1\rvert &= \dfrac{\lvert e^{2\pi i x} - 1\rvert}{\lvert e^{i(\frac\pi2 + \pi x)}\rvert}\\
&= \left\lvert\dfrac{e^{2\pi i x} - 1}{e^{i(\frac\pi2 + \pi x)}}\right\rvert\\
&= \left\lvert\dfrac{e^{\pi i x} - e^{-\pi i x}}{e^{i\frac\pi2}}\right\rvert\\
&= \left\lvert\dfrac{e^{\pi i x} - e^{-\pi i x}}{i}\right\rvert\\
&= 2\left\lvert\dfrac{e^{\pi i x} - e^{-\pi i x}}{2i}\right\rvert\\
&= 2\lvert \sin \pi x\rvert
\end{align}
$$
Since $\sin \pi x \geq 0$ on the interval $[0, 1]$, the goal integral simplifies to
$$2\int_0^1 \sin \pi x \, \mathrm{d}x = \dfrac4\pi$$

Very nice answer, thank you!
